# Which one is correct and why? the verb or the gerund

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

> Every one visiting these museums feels happy about it.

Or

> Every one visits these museums feels happy about it.

Comment: Both "visits" and "visiting" are **verbs**. Your first example is OK, but the second is ungrammatical.

Comment: In the second sentence: *Everyone visits these museums **and** feels happy about it*. With that one change, both sentences are grammatical, and the choice between them is entirely up to you.

Answer (score -2):

**Neither.**
It would rather be:

Every one visiting these museums is feeling happy about it.

Or

Every one who visits these museums feels happy about it.